# Are all energetic states of electrons in atoms whole number multiples of a specific wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

Are all energetic states of electrons in atoms whole number multiples of a specific wavelength associated with electrons in general, or are the the whole-number wave length intervals between the possible energetic states of electrons in atoms unique to each element?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here - what do you mean by the "wavelength" of an electron state?

Comment: Are you talking about the wavelengths of the electromagnetic spectrum of an atom? Or in some way about the wave-function of the atomic states? In either case, why are you expect whole-number multiples?

Answer (score 1):

No. All electronic transitions of electron are not multiples of some fundamental number. However there are series of transitions that fall into a clear pattern. For example the [various series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Series) for hydrogen.